# Delphi XE6 teechart in-box component error

Tags: delphi, teechart

Delphi XE6 I put TDBChart or TChart component an empty vcl form.
After right click on and select "Option..." -> Error reading Button1.Onclick: Invalid property value.

or Right click on and select "Edit chart...":
-Add a new series.
-Select the new series -> Acces vialation 'vcl200.bpl'. Error reading ELegendTitle.OnChange: Invalid property value.

I can`t use these component, not work for me, not edit series propertis.

Any advice, help?

Thanks, Csaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in our current sources and we are going to publish a free update for XE6 users. Please stay tuned.

Comment: Update available since 5/19/2014 at
[EDN](http://cc.embarcadero.com/results.aspx?id=29881)